# Error running 'ionic emulate ios' command

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ios-simulator

I've installed and build ios and all seems ok but when I run 'ionic emulate ios' I get the following error (just running it for the demo myApp):

Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Running command: /Users/X/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/X/myApp
add to body class: platform-ios
Running command: /Users/X/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/run --emulator
/bin/sh: ios-sim: command not found

Error: /Users/X/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed `ios-sim`?

```
sudo npm install -g ios-sim
```

Fix the hooks error permission:

```
chmod +x hooks/after_prepare/*
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems that you do not give 'execute permission' to cordova hooks, so just run:

```
chmod -R +x hooks/after_prepare
```

more about hooks issues: http://ionicframework.com/docs/ionic-cli-faq/#hooks.

Secondly, use ionic cli start ios simulator, you must install a utility package called ios-sim:

```
sudo npm install -g ios-sim
```

more about ios emulation:http://ionicframework.com/docs/ionic-cli-faq/#ios-emulate.

Hope this will help you. Regards.